# Firebase query all users who are not friends with user - flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview

I'm trying to make social media app using flutter. one key feature with apps like this is looking for friends, and I would like to implement this in my app.

Here's a look in my Firestore Database:
[image]

We have a collection of "users" where we store their data and a subcollection "friends" where we store the userID of the added users:
[image]

Let's say user "4uuBry" is friends with user "5083CM", then "5083CM" should not be seen in a list of friend suggestion for "4uuBry".

So how do I query all users who are not friends with "4uuBry" and display them in a ListView?

Comment: You'll first have to query all friend of "4uuBry" and then if you want to query "users" collection where the userId is **NOT-IN** list of user's friends. Firestore has a `not-in` operator but you can only provide 10 userIds at once.

Comment: Does the above comment helped you?

Comment: @RoopaM it gave me a hint, although I don't know how to apply it. it will only limit 10 friends to compare from all users. I am thinking the alternative of using friends as an array in the user document rather than a sub-collection but still weighing its pros and cons

Comment: For implementing `NOT-IN` operator you can refer this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in) and for pros and crons of array check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#nested_data_in_documents) and this [link](https://proandroiddev.com/working-with-firestore-building-a-simple-database-model-79a5ce2692cb#:~:text=When%20should%20I%20nest%20a%20collection%20in%20Firestore%3F)